# How to work with mechanise python

Tags: python, web-scraping, mechanize

I am trying to get some data from one news website. To do that I need to use internal search engine of the website. I think there is some problem in getting javascript generated content can this be a problem?

```
import mechanize
br = mechanize.Browser()
search_for = 'stack'
url = 'http://www.delfi.lt/paieska/?q={}'.format(search_for)
htmlfile = br.open(url)
webtext = htmlfile.read()
print webtext
```

I expcet that this would return all text including search results. However, it does not return search results.

I got voted down. It is ok, but please provide me with feedback, what is wrong with my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are using custom google search, loaded through javascript. You have three options:

- Load the page in a headless browser, like phantomjs/casperjs.
- Replicate their javascript in Python. (bad option)
- Use googles search API yourself.

You really cannot use mechanize for such tasks.